# Obtaining data from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a java application that can create a Socketed lan server to parse information from a website, with the main goal of collecting chat data. At first I was in a test version of that website and was able to just open a web socket in a chrome extension then save it toward the Java server. Now that I have went to the public version of the site where its actually heavily protected, the site has the Content Security Policy, that disallows the use of Web Sockets from chrome extensions. I am unsure if there is any possible way to transfer that chat data from the site to the server via google chrome extension or any other way.

Comment: Connect to your site in the background script and use messaging to communicate with the content script, [more info](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches).

Comment: Alright will try that.

Comment: Alright I tried using messaging with content scripts and that will require me to upload my chrome extension to the web. I can do that sure but it says it will takes weeks to verify my extension, and I would rather not wait that long. Are there any other options that I have for sending data from an extension?

Comment: Would using an additional extension to cross that information be possible? I see that Chrome.extension is deprecated so I am not sure if I can.

Comment: There's no need to upload anything, there's no need for `chrome.extension` either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to open a socket inside of the Website itself. "wOxxOm" gave me a lead that you cannot do that and I later on understood that you had to use websockets in the background.js of the chrome extension.